# PHP/MySQL : Generate unique id

Tags: multi-user, form-submit

How to generate a unique id after form submission in multiuser environment using PHP and MySQL. I am using WAMP.

Comment: create a column in your table (typically named ID) and set it to be [auto-incrementing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 1):

since you're using wamp I'm assuming you're using phpmyadmin. Inside phpmyadmin you need to create a database, and your table.

All you have to do after that is add a field called ID, make it the primary key (since its the unique value). Also make sure its an int and check the column field A/I is checked.